# day minus one method to calculate business day c#

Tags: .net, windows, c#-4.0

I've been working on a project where a date is calculated based on a number of days added to current DateTime.Now. I'm using several functions based on this work: [business dates calculation](http://tinyurl.com/884kojy) , and since this requires a calculation of business days (no weekend days or holidays are calculated, holidays are coded to an app config file), the count needs to start on the current date "now", or the previous business day if start is on a weekend day or holiday. The *current* class file always moves *ahead* to the next business day before starting the count. If the start date is today, the count will start tomorrow.

My requirements for example: a start day of 1/21/2012 is a Saturday. A value of 10 days is added. The resulting date *should be* February 2. This means the business day to start a calculation is Friday January 20 + 9 more days = 10 days. Another example would be to set the start on Sunday January 22, stepping back to January 20, and add 9 days with the same result. Provided The count does not start on weekends or holidays, it should skip them and arrive at the next calculated business day.

The issue I'm having is my project needs to calculate based on the current date, or step back to the previous business day if the count start is a weekend or holiday.

I think the class file is very clear, but I cant seem to find a way to force the count to start on the current business day, or step backward to the previous business day if the count start is a weekend or holiday.

Please have a look at the code in the link. I've attempted to add negative values to the addDays param in several of the existing methods; in my form I've tried to force the dateTimePicker value to subtract a day, and a variety of other thrashings about throughout the class file, resulting in failure.

Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated!

Code in button click event:

```
 //DateTime.Today.AddDays(-4);

         DateTime date = dateTimePicker1.Value;
        // dateTimePicker1.Value.AddDays(-2);
        XDateTime sDate = new XDateTime(dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString(), XDateTimeType.Business);

        string Str = textBox2.Text.Trim();
        string Str2 = textBox3.Text.Trim();

        double Num;
        bool isNum = double.TryParse(Str, out Num);
        bool isNum2 = double.TryParse(Str2, out Num);
        label6.Text = "";

        //Test whether textBox contains a number or some other character. Fails if not a number.
        if (isNum)
        {
            short days = Convert.ToInt16(textBox2.Text);
            sDate.AddBusinessDays(days);

            lblTodaysDate.Text = " Substantial Completion Date: " + sDate.Date.ToString("MMMM d, yyyy");
            label3.Text = "";

            if (isNum2)
            {
                short days2 = Convert.ToInt16(textBox3.Text);
                sDate.AddBusinessDays(days2);
                label6.Text = " Physical Completion Date: " + sDate.Date.ToString("MMMM d, yyyy");
                label5.Text = "";
            }
            else
                label5.Text = "Please enter numbers only!";             
            return;
        }
        else
           label3.Text = "Please enter numbers only!";
        return;
```

Comment: Can you be a little more concise about what your question is? I have had a similar problem but I chose to create a function called `AddWorkDays(byVal days as Integer, byVal Holidays as List(of DateTime))` This way I can pass the holidays I want to skip to the function. It looks like the way yours is set up, each `XDateTime` stores its own holidays.

Comment: Please post some code here showing your attempt at the method that's giving you trouble.

Comment: Added the button click event into the original question. Sorry, I'm not sure how to place formated code into the comments. What I need to have happen is for the day to start the count be the date from the date time picker, not the next business day.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The modification to the method below results in the count starting on the selected day rather than the next business. This resolves the issue. Thank you to all who commented!

```
public void AddBusinessDays(short days)
    {
        double sign = Convert.ToDouble(Math.Sign(days));
        int unsignedDays = Math.Sign(days) * days -1; //*days; added -1 to force count to start on selected day, rather than next business day.
        for (int i = 0; i < unsignedDays; i++)
        {
            do
            {
                _date = _date.AddDays(sign);
            }
            while (!this.IsWorkDay);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you read the article you link to?

It contains the following snippet for calculating the previous business day:

```
do 
{
   date = date.AddDays(-1.0);
}
while (date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday || date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday || 
    _holidays.ContainsValue(date.ToString(_format)));
```

It also contains a method for forcing the date to be a business day, which chooses the next business day:

```
private void check()
{
   if (_type == XDateTimeType.Business && !this.IsWorkDay)
   {
      _date = this.NextBusinessDay();
   }
}
```

If you consistently want to start from the previous day, change the `check` method to call `PreviousBusinessDay`.  Or create an analogous `checkPrevious` method.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the comment. Yes, I did read the article. Perhaps I'm doing something incorrectly, but the method  for the previous business day does not step back to the previous business day as expected - I don't know why. What does work in this situation for weekends and holidays, is to assign -1 to the Next Business Day method. I do not want to start consistently from the previous business day (or the next), rather it should start the count on the date assigned.

Comment: And for the comment I just made, what I've discovered is that the seeting of -1 on the Next Business day works if the start day falls on a saturday, if on sunday then moves to monday to begin the count. The count should always begin on the previous business day if the selected date to start is a Saturday, Sunday, or Holiday. Otherwise the days should be skipped altogether in the count.